# vsftpd installation on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, vsftpd

**I'm use Linux server with vsftpd connection created successfully but i can't retrieve the files**

[image: where is problem here ?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp

sudo service vsftpd restart

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that the connection timed out when trying to transfer something (`LIST`) after switching to Passive Mode (`PASV`). In my opinion, probably your firewall is not correctly configured for Passive Mode and therefore is blocking the connection.

Try allowing incoming (inbound) connections on port 40000 to 50000 for all IP address or the IP address of your FTP client. Configuring firewall is firewall-specific, therefore, I cannot give you detailed instruction on how to do this.

Comment: After
sudo ufw allow 40000:50000/tcp
service vsftpd restart
thats worked thanks man